# start python script as background process from within a python script

Tags: python

My python script needs to start a background process and then continue processing to completion without waiting for a return.

The background script will process for some time and will not generate any screen output.

There is no inter-process data required.

I have tried using various methods subprocess, multiprocessing but am clearly missing something.

Does anyone have a simple example?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

```
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process

Process(target=subprocess.call, args=(('ls', '-l', ), )).start()
```

It's not all that elegant, but it fulfils all your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
subprocess.Popen(["background-process", "arguments"])
```

If you want to check later whether the background process completed its job, retain a reference to the Popen object and use it's `poll()` method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice writeup of the various pieces/parts on how to do it at [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python/92395) (per @lecodesportif).

The gist of a quick answer is:

```
retcode = subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Comment: It fails the "without waiting" requirement.

Comment: Ah - my bad, I missed that in the reading. You're quite correct. Stefano's answer should do what you want then.

Comment: What about something like: `retcode = subprocess.call(["ls -l &"], shell=True)`. That works for me.