# How to run multiple programs in different consoles in Python

Tags: python

I have two folders, `1` and `2`. Each folder has a Python file with the same name: `220_beta_1e-2_47_53ND.py`. How do I run both the Python files simultaneously on different consoles? I mostly use Spyder.

Comment: what is your operative system? also, you can just do it with a third script that starts 2 processes

Comment: I am on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

on powershell (replace XYZ with your python version)

```
 Invoke-Item C:\PythonXYZ\python.exe pathtoscript1; Invoke-Item C:\PythonXYZ\python.exe pathtoscript2;
```

or rather create a third script in python that launches 2 processes

Comment: Can you suggest how I can write a python script that launches 2 scripts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595685/start-python-script-as-background-process-from-within-a-python-script